# Rules applied to the separation of syllables

Tags: sílabas

As a native speaker it's natural for me to know how a word is separated in its constituent syllables. But I want to know if there are any established rules to know how a word is separated into its syllables.

For example:

> camión = ca-mión
>
> sol = sol
>
> cielo = cie-lo

Comment: A really nice question! I've always thought that this syllabic separation matter is one of the most counter-intuitive facts in any language.

Comment: In my experience those languages which have academies or some other kind of standardizing bodies, always have very specific set out rules for syllabification.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is an [interesting guide](http://www.spanishdict.com/answers/100865/syllables-how-to-divide-a-word-in-spanish-by-lazarus) I found on Spanishdict.com. I'll try to sum up the content here for easy reference:

1. ***Diphthongs** are considered as a single syllable*. They are formed by joining a closed vowel (i, u) with an open vowel (a, e, o). «*The possible combinations are ai, ei, oi, au, eu, ou, ia, ie, io, ua, ue, uo, iu and ui.*»; the **h** makes no difference.
2. ***Hiatus** is considered as two syllables (two vowels)*. Two open vowels together are called *hiatus*. An open vowel and a closed vowel make a hiatus, if the closed vowel has a tilde. «*(e.g. ía, eí)*»; the **h** makes no difference.
3. *A **triphthong** is a single syllable with 3 vowels*. The middle one must always be an open vowel, and the other two must be unstressed closed vowels «*(otherwise, it will be a vowel plus a diphthong)*».
4. *The **"U"** in "qu" and "gu" before -i and -e are not considered vowels.* If you want the u to be pronounced, you must use the dieresis: *"Guerra"* vs *"Lingüística"*. Note: the dieresis can only appear in the "gu" syllable, not in the "qu" one.
5. *The letter **"H"** is completely ignored when counting syllables**.
6. *The digraphs **ch, ll, rr, qu and gu (before e and i)** form a single syllable.* However, the rr is split if it is clear from its etymology, as in inter-relacionado.
7. ***Consonants between vowels** always belong to the second one.*
8. *The consonants **(b, c, d, f, g, k, p, t)** followed by R or L are not divisible.* Plus «*The exceptions to this rule are words with prefixes, such as At-lán-ti-co, sub-li-mi-nal, which are also pronounced separately. Also, the sequences tl and dl are separated or not depending on the country, but they are generally split*».
9. «*Any other two consecutive consonants not mentioned so far, will belong to two different syllables (e.g. ac-ción), unless they are at the beginning of a word (e.g. psi-có-lo-go)».*
10. «*When three consonants appear together, the last one will belong to a different syllable, unless it is an r or an s (e.g. ins-truir)*».

---

**Note**: the parts between « » (parts in point 1, 2, 3, 8 and points 9, and 10 are directly quoted from the site, i.e. copy-pasted.)

By the way, I found this "[Silabeitor](http://www.poemas-del-alma.com/silabas.php)". Enter the word with correct tilde and it will divide it.

Comment: Following the rules for hyphenation... I'm not sure you wanted them. If you do, I'll include them.

Comment: I personally think it would be natural to pronounce "ae" and "oe" as diphthongs. Latin itself pronounces pronounces "ae" and "oe" as diphthongs.

Comment: "Note: the dieresis can only appear in the 'gu' syllable, not in the 'qu' one." We do have words with "qüe" and "qüi", but those are mostly loanwords.