# How to pronounce "criar"?

Tags: verbos, pronunciación, diptongos

I was taught that when a "weak" vowel (i, u) combines with a "strong" vowel (a, e, o) you pronounce them as a single syllable diphthong. But an online dictionary says that the verb [criar is pronounced with two syllables](https://www.spanishdict.com/translate/criar). At least in the pronunciation popup they spell it "kree-ahr".

Is there another rule governing the pronunciation of "criar" that says it should be considered two syllables?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, *criar* is pronounced (by everybody I know, at least) with two syllables, /kri.ar/. This is a violation of the rule that says that a so-called "weak"¹ vowel (/i/ or /u/) always forms a diphthong with a following "strong" vowel.² It's not the only one: it appears (for some people, not all) in several other verb [infinitives ending in *-iar* or *-uar*](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/19445/por-qu%C3%A9-los-verbos-terminados-en-iar-se-dividen-en-dos-acentuaciones-distint) such as *enviar* and *actuar*. ([This answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/1535/14627) and part of [this answer](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/25721/14627) are also relevant to your question.) It also happens in many other words that are not verb forms, such as adjectives (*dual*, *fiable*) and nouns (*cliente*, *cruento*).

The hiatus (i.e. the breaking of the expected diphthong) is unpredictable, but it tends to appear, [according to studies](http://prosodia.upf.edu/home/arxiu/publicacions/cabre/cabre_exceptional_hiatuses_spanish.pdf), due to two main kinds of factors: morphological and phonological.

The morphological factors can be summarized like this: **a diphthong will be broken in a word if it gets broken in words with the same root.** So for example, since the present tense of the verb *enviar* are *envío*, *envías*, *envía*, etc. with a hiatus (shown by the accented *í*), the infinitive *enviar* itself will be influenced and will be pronounced with a hiatus, *en-vi-ar*.³ There's more to it than that but that's the idea.

The phonological factors include the presence of a liquid (*r* or *l*) in the onset of the syllable, i.e. before the main vowel. In *criar* we have a stop consonant /k/ (*c*), plus a liquid /r/, plus a vowel /i/ that should phonetically become a glide or semivowel [j] (like the English *y* in *yet*); in many words this pileup seems to be too much so the speakers spontaneously break the syllable in two to preserve a simpler structure: /kri/ + /ar/. This may be also what happens with *cliente* and *cruento*. (Again, there are more factors in play.)

Spanish marks basically everything in orthography, but it doesn't show this irregular hiatus in any way.

---

¹ "Weak" vowels are technically **close** vowels, while "strong" vowels are **open** (/a/) or **mid** (/e/ and /o/) vowels.

² Actually any "weak" vowel is apt to form a diphthong with another vowel, of either type; *iu* and *ui* are possible.

³ The subset of the *-ar* class of verbs with an infinitive that ends in *-iar* or *-uar* is thus divided into two subclasses: those where the diphthong is kept (like *anunciar, cambiar, averiguar, menguar*), and those where the diphthong is broken in certain persons and tenses (like *criar, enviar, adecuar, actuar*). See the RAE's [conjugation paradigms](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/modelos-de-conjugacion-verbal).