# Why does 'mohínes' have an accent?

Tags: ortografía, acentuación, hiato

I came across the following sentence in *El año del diluvio* by Eduardo Mendoza:

> *La guardesa depositó la bandeja y se marchó haciendo mohínes*

Why does *mohínes* have an accent? According to WordReference the singular is *mohín*. As far as I was aware, singular nouns that have a stress on the last syllable – like *organización* – lose the written accent in the plural – *organizaciones*. This is because in words without a written accent (and ending with a vowel, *n*, or *s*), the stress is assumed to fall on the penultimate syllable. If *mohín* followed this rule, then shouldn't the plural be *mohines*?

---

Encontré la siguiente oración en *El año del diluvio* por Eduardo Mendoza:

> *La guardesa depositó la bandeja y se marchó haciendo mohínes*

¿Porqué lleva *mohínes* un acento? Según WordReference, el singular es *mohín*. A mi entiendo, sustantivos singulares que llevan agudo en la sílaba última – como *organización* – pierden el agudo en el plural – *organizaciones*. Esto se debe al hecho de que el acento de las palabras sin agudo (y terminado con *s*), cae en la sílaba penúltima. Si *mohín* cumpliera esa regla, sería *mohines* en el plural.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In this case I think you are (understandably) being misled by the medial *h*. The *h* is not only mute, but also it doesn't have any effect on [syllable division](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/812/rules-applied-to-the-separation-of-syllables/).<sup>1</sup> So you must imagine *mohín* would have the same written acute accent if it were written **moín*. It's not the case that the *h* in *mohín* is making *-hín* a separate syllable; that is being marked by the acute accent.

In Spanish, "open" vowels *a, e* and *o* usually form diphthongs with "closed" vowels *i* and *u*. When they don't it's because the "closed" vowel is stressed, and this stress is always orthographically marked by the acute accent.

The *o* and the *í* are in **hiatus**, i.e. they don't form a diphthong as they normally would. The acute accent over *í* marks both stress and the fact that the *í* is on a different syllable: *mo-hín*, *mo-hí-nes*.

If you didn't write an acute accent in *mohín* and *mohínes*, they would be pronounced as *moin* and *moines*, i.e. as you would pronounce (in English) "moyn" and "moy-ness". Again, the *h* is totally irrelevant. The same thing, where the *h* doesn't break the diphthong, takes place in *[búho](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/2670/why-is-b%C3%BAho-written-with-an-acute-accent-por-qu%C3%A9-lleva-acento-la-palabra-b%C3%BA?rq=1)*; and the same kind of thing that happens with *mohín* happens with *maíz* (pl. *maíces*) and *tahúr* (pl. *tahúres*).

---

<sup>**1.** "La presencia de una hache intercalada no exime de la obligación de tildar la vocal tónica del hiato: *búho, ahíto, prohíbe.*"</sup>
<sup>([DPD: Tilde](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Adwesaq4ND64VT09xQ) - 2.2.2.b *Acentuación de las palabras con hiato*)</sup>